# Internal Server Error nginx using ip_hash sticky load balancer

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm new on docker, and I'm trying to create a stickiness engine in nginx load balancer (once I get a response from one server, I stay on this server for 5 minutes) by using a cookie that I've created on my python app, containning the internal IP address, that expires in 5 minutes.
I don't have nginx plus so to create stickiness i'm using `ip_hash` method.
When I'm entering `localhost` to the url I'm getting here:

[image]

The problem is that after 5 minutes, when my cookie is deleted, instead of moving to a different server I'm getting:

> Internal Server Error.
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Here is the part from my app.py that I'm creating the cookie:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
global counter
counter += 1

# Get internal IP address
internal_ip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']

# Create cookie with internal IP address that expires in 5 minutes
resp = make_response(internal_ip)
try:
    resp.set_cookie('internal_ip', internal_ip, max_age=300)
    print("cookie created successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    app.logger.exception(f"Error setting cookie: {e}")
# some code....

return resp
```

nginx.conf - `app-1`, `app-2`, `app-3` are name container's name of the app's replicas:

```
events {
worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    upstream app {
    ip_hash;
    server app-1:5000;
    server app-2:5000;
    server app-3:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Cookie "internal_ip=$cookie_internal_ip";
     }
  }
}
```